# Why does gcc -std=c99 treat the keyword asm as a function?

Tags: gcc

I have a simple program:

```
int main() {
   asm ("movl    $-2, %ecx");
   return 0;
}
```

When I build the program with

```
gcc soc.c
```

it builds file without any problems. However, when I build it with

```
gcc -std=c99 soc.c
```

I get the following error message.

```
soc.c: In function ‘main’:
soc.c:2:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘asm’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    asm ("movl    $-2, %ecx");
    ^
/cygdrive/c/Users/rsahu/AppData/Local/Temp/ccEMHjZ4.o:soc.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `asm'
/cygdrive/c/Users/rsahu/AppData/Local/Temp/ccEMHjZ4.o:soc.c:(.text+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `asm'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does the use of `-std=c99` change how the keyword `asm` is treated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does the use of -std=c99 change how the keyword asm is treated?

Because the `asm` keyword is *not* part of the C standard. It's a GNU extension. So without `-std=c99`, gcc accepts it as gcc extensions are enabled. The default mode mode for gcc (when `-std` is not explicitly specified) is `gnu90` or `gnu11` depending on the version of gcc compiler.

Comment: For some reason, I was under the false impression that `asm` is a keyword in the language, and the interpretation of the argument was left to the compiler. Thanks for the clarification.